# Where does ajaxSubmitButton's javascript get moved to?

Tags: php, yii

I have a CActiveForm inside a CJuiDialog and within that a CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton that looks something like this:

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton($name,
    "/content/createlightbox/id/{$model->LightboxID}",
    array(
        'data'=>'js:$("#lightbox-form").serialize()',
        'success'=>'function(data)
        {
            // close the dialog
        }'
    ), array('id' => 'send-link-'.uniqid())
);
```

I set up an XHR Breakpoint in Chrome Developer Tools and locally I see Javascript in the call stack under "`(anonymous function) VM1018:8`".  So where is Yii putting that Javascript??  I don't see it anywhere else.  Is Chrome somehow hiding it from me?

The problem I'm having is that this works (the dialog gets closed) on my local machine but not in production and it appears to be because the form is not being submitted through ajax.  But I feel like I need to see where Yii is putting the Javascript because it looks to me like JS needs to be wrapped in a document.ready function.

Comment: if you view the page source, is there any onclick on the button tag, also you could try looking for the `send-link-` in your code to see where that is.

Comment: or also look in the code to see where the .serialize() is being called from, I would expect it to be in the same place as the success code

Comment: No onclick on the button and neither send-link- nor the serialize() can be found in either the source or when inspecting the code.

Answer (score -1):

It's in the bottom of your page code. It will be something like:

```
jQuery('body').on('click','#your-form_submit_115',function(){jQuery.ajax ....
```

You won't find it in source, go to elements in chrome and look scripts before `</body>`

Comment: Its not anywhere in the viewable source.  Obviously its getting delivered to the client but I've looked at the output from "View Source" and the "Elemeents" and "Sources" tabs in Developer Tools.  Its not there.  The only way I can ever see that JS is clicking the "VM1018:8" and I only get that because that code is throwing a runtime error.

Comment: It's inserted into page code, so look in it. And it's there, and always been.